# Disk not shown in Solaris 11.1 format tool

Tags: hard-drive, solaris-11, format

I have a Sun Fire T2000 with up-to-date firmware, running Solaris 11.1.

I have inserted two SEAGATE-ST914602SSUN146G-0400-136.73GB HDDs in bays 2 and 3.

Both drives show OK in the ALOM and are visible to raidctl. However, the disk in bay 2 does not show up in the format tool, whilst the disk in bay 3 does.

Any suggestions as to how to make format see the drive?

```
ALOM:

Disk   Status            Service  OK2RM
--------------------------------------------
HDD0   OK                OFF      OFF
HDD1   OK                OFF      OFF
HDD2   OK                OFF      OFF
HDD3   OK                OFF      OFF
```

Many thanks.

@jillagre:

```
svcs -xv devfsadm
svc:/system/devfsadm:default (hot-plug and synchronous device support service)
 State: online since June 19, 2013 11:28:33 AM BST
   See: man -M /usr/share/man -s 1M devfsadm
   See: /var/svc/log/system-devfsadm:default.log
Impact: None.
```

@Sirch:

```
dsk/c2t2d0 is missing

cfgadm -al
Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
c2                             scsi-sas     connected    configured   unknown
c2::dsk/c2t0d0                 disk         connected    configured   unknown
c2::dsk/c2t1d0                 disk         connected    configured   unknown
c2::dsk/c2t3d0                 disk         connected    configured   unknown
c3                             scsi-bus     connected    configured   unknown
c3::dsk/c3t0d0                 CD-ROM       connected    configured   unknown
```

Comment: What says `svcs -xv devfsadm` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks a lot like raidctl has established some sort of raid on them already and handing the OS a single raided target.

Does the output of `raidctl` and `raidctl -l c2t3d0` confirm this? If so, youll want to remove this raided with

```
raidctl -d c2t3d0
```

Then cfgadm -al will hopefully give you your 2 devices without rebooting.

Comment: The disk doesn't show there unfortunately. Please see my edited question. Thank you.

Comment: @retrodev updated answer.

Comment: Ah, yes it does look that way. I didn't expect Solaris 11.1 installer to do that given it was using ZFS. This is a clean build so I'll try removing the RAID volume. Thank you.

Comment: c2t3d0 had been added into a RAID volume all on its own, hence format not seeing it. Not sure if Solaris 11.1 installer did this or not, but simply deleting the RAID volume was enough to allow format to see the disk.

Comment: Awesome, did you need to reboot or did cfgadm -al pick up the devices after you raidctl -d <volume>?

Comment: No, it picked it up right away.